# Store a text file in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Im trying to read a text file and store this information in a linked list.
The text File has the following structure:

```
//comments
<car>
<model>model</model>
<model>differentmodel</model>
<cylinders>6</cylinders>
<Owners>
<NumberofOnwners>2</NumberofOwners>
<FirstOwner> FirstOwner </FirstOwner>
<SecondOwner>SecondOwner</SecondOwner>
</Owners>
<Dimensions>
<Length>4.3</Length>
<Width>2.1</Width>
</Dimensions>
</car>
```

I now want to read in a text file and save the information in a linked list of cars. All lines that begin with // should be ignored.
Complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256



struct _starr 
{
    int count;
    char string[10][30];
};

struct _Dim 
{
    float length;
    float width;
};

typedef struct _Car 
{
    int cylinders;
    struct _starr Owners;
    struct _Dim Dimensions;
    struct _starr models;
    struct _Car *prev;
    struct _Car *next;
} Car;

typedef struct _List
{
   int num;
   Car *head;
   Car *tail; 
};

char filtering[100];
char filtered[100];
char *token1;
char *token2;

int fnAdd (struct _List *list,Car *pCar)
{

    Car *ptr = list->head;
    if(ptr)
    {
        pCar->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = pCar;
        list->tail = pCar;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = pCar;
        list->tail = pCar;
    }
    list->num++;
}
int main(void)
{
    Car *pCar;
    struct _List List;

    List.num = 0;
    List.head = NULL;
    List.tail = NULL;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Failed: ");
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[MAX_LEN];

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, fp)) 
    {
      if (buffer[0] == '/') continue;
      buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

        if (strncmp(buffer, "<car>", 5) == 0) 
        {
            printf("Found Car!");

        }
        else if (strncmp(buffer, "<cylinders>", 11) == 0) 
        {
            token1 = strtok(buffer, ">");

            while (token1 != NULL) 
            {
                strncpy(filtering, token1, sizeof(filtering));
                token1 = strtok(NULL, ">");
            }

            token2 = strtok(filtering, "<");

            strncpy(filtered, token2, sizeof(filtered));
            strncpy(pCar->cylinders, filtered, sizeof(pCar->models));
            memset(filtering, 0, sizeof(filtering));
            memset(filtered, 0, sizeof(filtered));
        }

        else if (strncmp(buffer, "<Owners>", 8) == 0) 
        {
            token1 = strtok(buffer, ">");

            while (token1 != NULL) 
            {
                strncpy(filtering, token1, sizeof(filtering));
                token1 = strtok(NULL, ">");
            }

            token2 = strtok(filtering, "<");

            strncpy(filtered, token2, sizeof(filtered));
            strncpy(pCar->Owners, filtered, sizeof(pCar->Owners));
            memset(filtering, 0, sizeof(filtering));
            memset(filtered, 0, sizeof(filtered));
        }
    }
 fnAdd(&List,pCar);
}
```

This did not work. I am also unsure about how to store multiple owners in a char array and how to store the dimensions. The last else if statement did not work, since i don't know how to use strncopy with a char array.

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly.

Comment: Have you considered using an xml parser, rather than writing another one by yourself? What created this output?

Comment: Your sample data file appears to be malformed. It has `<Dimensions>` but does _not_ have a corresponding `</Dimensions>`

Comment: @CraigEstey yes, fixed

Comment: @Rogue im using vscode and code runner. If I try to print the list,  outputs a path to the code runner directory

Comment: @SupportUkraine forgot to count <>... also added the add to list function

Comment: Your plain text looks suspiciously like xml. Maybe use an xml library?

Comment: @bitmask Do you know of any library that would allow me to store the information in a struct? And would that library be able to match the variables to the text, e.g. store model in the model char array?

Comment: at some point you need to allocate memory for the nodes you're adding to the list, I don't see that anywhere. What's `pPerson`?

Comment: @yano yes but im still not sure if I am even storing the right information in the Car struct, I didn't  give too much thought about adding it to the linked list. pPerson is from another file, accidentally added that

Comment: Please do _us/you_ a favor: post your _entire_ program (with `#include`) in a _single_ code block. I know the MRE page said to split them up, but 99.44% of the responders here [for the `c` tag] explicitly ask for a _single_ code block that compiles _cleanly_. With the snippets you've posted, even when combining them, there are _numerous_ syntax errors. The struct definitions are out of order. `struct _Car` --> `struct _car`. The definition for `struct _car` should [probably] have `typedef` before it. And, the last token should be `Car` and _not_ `car`. Many other such mismatches.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, edited. I know it should compile cleanly, but the last else if statement always throws an error because I'm trying to use strncpy with a char array.

Comment: What do you want to happen when, _eg_, `<model>model</model><model>differentmodel</model>`? Is it a syntax error to have more than one? `<Owners><NumberofOnwners>2</NumberofOwners><FirstOwner> FirstOwner </FirstOwner><SecondOwner>SecondOwner</SecondOwner></Owners>` is a headache to parse and verify; are you open to improvements in the syntax of xml-like data?

Comment: @Neil both the model and differentmodel should be stored in the model array. Im sorry, but it the text file has to be in this format.

Comment: I anticipate a problem `<ThousandOneHundredSixtyFifthOwner>` (like, what is a [billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion)?) unless the owners are capped somehow. How do you handle `<NumberofOnwners>7` three are specified? I think the `model` could go into a separate table with a foreign key.